# Error on installing Passenger with Nginx on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nginx, passenger, production-environment, ubuntu-19.04

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and was facing the following issue to setup Passenger/Nginx on running the command
`sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger`:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (< 1.14.1) but
>   1.15.9-0ubuntu1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Then I updated "bionic" to "disco" in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list file (because codename for Ubuntu 19.04 is "disco") and got the following issue on installing ibnginx-mod-http-passenger:

> E: Unable to locate package libnginx-mod-http-passenger

Can anyone help how can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Passenger support and they told me that on ubuntu 19.04, packages are not yet released due to being blocked on their migration to a new linux package host.

Reference: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2104#issuecomment-516026126

So I purchased a server with Ubuntu 16.04 and setup Passenger/Nginx without an issue. You can follow the following tutorial to setup Ubuntu 16.04 server:
https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04